# Chain builtin commands with external commands in VIM

Tags: git, vim

Is there a way to chain external commmands into built in commands on the vim command line? I wanted to do something like this:

```
vsp !git diff --name-only
```

I have tried

```
vsp system('git', 'diff', '--name-only')
```

and

```
vsp `!git diff --name-only\`
```

(y'know, just in case. Other bash things seem to just work in vim) to no avail. Does anybody know of a way to do this. I would of course only have modified one file. Thanks in advance!

I also tried `:execute "vsplit " . !git diff --name-only`, `vsplit exec "!git diff --name-only"`, and `:execute "vsplit " . exec "!git diff --name-only"`. No luck

Comment: Do you want to have the output of `git diff --name-only` put into a new vertical split?

Comment: No, I want to open the changed file in a new buffer in a split window. the output of `git diff --name-only` will be a relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- EDIT --

So I was completely off…

You only need to put `git diff --name-only` between backticks:

```
:vsplit `git diff --name-only`
```

Be aware that `:vsplit`, like `:edit` and friends only takes **one** argument so the command above will fail if you have two or more files.

You should probably use `:next` instead:

```
:vnew|next `git diff --name-only`
```

-- ENDEDIT --

You could do something like this:

```
:vnew|0r!git diff --name-only
```

- create a new buffer in a vertical window,
- insert the output of `git diff --name-only` at the top of that empty buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this creates a new buffer with the output of the command, which is /path/to/file in this case. I wanted to open that file as though I was entering :vsplit /path/to/file

Comment: So the backtick thing with or without the `!` didn't work for me, it outputs _Can't find file "\`git diff --name-only\`" in runtime path`_. But the :next command was what I was missing. Thank you

Comment: As an addendum to my previous comment, apparently vsplit `git diff --name-only` does work, but Vsplit does not, which is what tab completes first. I don't know why that is. But, lowercase vsplit with no `!` and backticks works as @romainl said